# How to avoid protected class members?

Tags: c++, oop, protected

I have read in many discussions that having `protected` class members is bad and I see the reasons for that. But given the example below, what is the most elegant way to make `const int age` `private` and to solve the problem that arises from that?

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
    public:
        Animal(const int age) : age(age) {}
        void print_age() const { std::cout << age << std::endl; }
    protected:
        const int age;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
    public:
        Dog(const int age) : Animal(age) {}
        void bark() const
        {
            if (age >= 1)
                std::cout << "Woof!" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "(...)" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Dog dog(1);
    dog.print_age();
    dog.bark();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int getAge() const{ return age; }`?

Comment: If you make `age` private then you need to add accessors (i.e. get and set). But then will you make them public? Is age supposed to be modified outside the animal hierarchy? If not, you have to make it protected, and then you're back to the same problem.

Comment: @Default, isn't it odd to use accessor functions to retrieve variables from a base class?

Comment: @MariusBancila, no age is constant in the program and is not modified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're referring to reasons such as in [Why is Clean Code suggesting avoiding protected variables?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162643/why-is-clean-code-suggesting-avoiding-protected-variables), you also need to keep in mind that those guidelines are intended for real-world scenarios, where often inheritance hierarchies aren't as clearcut as Animal and Dog. With enterprise-level applications, it's tempting for many developers to think in terms of inheritance as if it would bring more organization in the future, but in reality variables are thoughtlessly thrown into the base class, over time bloating the structure and eroding the organizational context of its members.

In your simple case, using `protected` is fine.

Comment: So all in all, my solution does make sense and for programs with a simple structure it is alright to use `protected` in the way I am using it?

Comment: It does. In a larger application context though, an example of how it _wouldn't_ make sense is if there is no need to support any animal other than Dog for the foreseeable future, and you start putting `age` as well as other members in the base class. But of course, in that case you shouldn't have created `Animal` either. (It's a little tricky to analogize this example to something more real-world.)

Comment: You asked how you can avoid using `protected`. Well, _if_ the issue were that you're using a hierarchy where you don't need to, then the answer is: get rid of `Animal`. But obviously you have a good reason to use `Animal`, so that advice doesn't make sense. In the real-world case though, that is indeed the answer sometimes: "You're using the wrong structure to begin with." Or at least, "Just put it in the derived class, you won't use it in other classes." (But neither does that make sense for your example, where `age` does seem universal to `Animal`.)